# validation summary should show in alert message box?

Tags: c#, javascript, .net, asp.net-mvc-3

I have a view which contains a form. The controls have annotations in my model. I want that

```
    @Html.ValidationSummary();
```

will show in a alert Message Box.

Is there any way. I am new to mvc therefore please elaborate the answer.

Thanks in advance!!

Comment: What do you mean by a message box? A javascript alert?

Comment: right. A javascript alert can be a good option. Therefore I have edited the question.

Comment: you can't . there is no helper method. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.html.validationextensions.validationsummary(v=vs.108).aspx. need to create on your own. But Valid question, hope folks will answer soon

Comment: check [HERE](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10888000/mvc3-razor-jquery-client-side-validation-with-an-additional-alert-box)

Answer (score 3):

I don't have my computer with me so I can't provide an example but `@Html.ValidationSummary()` return a unorderd list of errors.  (see http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd460343(v=vs.108).aspx)

You could check if `@Html.ValidationSummary()` has a value in JavaScript and then use JQuery to pull out the text values of the `<li>` elements and put them in an alert.

Try this, I haven't tested it yet but it should be a guide:

```
<script>
var validationSummary = '@Html.ValidationSummary()';
var alerttext = '';
if (validationSummary !== '')
{
    $(validationSummary)
        .find('li').each( function()
        {
            alerttext = alerttext + $(this).text() + '\n';
        });

    alert(alerttext);

}

</script>
```